# Pause for a looped audio in Three.js

Tags: audio, three.js

I extensively use the Audio and PositionalAudio part of ThreeJS and it seems to me that the play/pause function can not work correctly for a looped audio.

In the ThreeJS Audio source we can read:

```js
this._pausedAt += Math.max( this.context.currentTime - this._startedAt, 0 ) * this.playbackRate;
```

If I am understand correctly, `_pausedAt` is thus somehow the *elapsed duration of play in the audio file* which is fine and totally usable (in particular for a straightforward playing with no loop).  But when executing the `play()` function I see:

```js
source.start( this._startedAt, this._pausedAt + this.offset, this.duration );
```

And in the MDN documentation of `AudioBufferSourceNode.start()`:

```
offsets past the end of the audio which will be played (based on the audio 
buffer's duration and/or the loopEnd property) are silently clamped to the 
maximum value allowed.
```

That means that once the file has been read at least once until the end (with or without pauses), the next `play()` (typically after a `pause()`) will start at the end of the file (`duration` and/or `loopEnd` as mentioned) instead of restarting from the correct position where it was paused – somewhere in between `loopStart` and `loopEnd`.

Am I correct on this understanding?

If so, I see no better option than doing something like the code below to *correct* the position of the *playhead* (or `_pausedAt`):

```js
if (sound.getLoop() === true) {
  var looping = (sound.loopEnd === 0) ? sound.source.buffer.duration : sound.loopEnd
  var loopDur = looping - sound.loopStart
  _pausedAt = (_pausedAt - sound.loopStart) % loopDur + sound.loopStart;
}
```

Does any of this make sense?

Thank you very much,

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Answered on ThreeJS discourse: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/pause-for-looped-audio/16894
Fixed here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/19079

Answer (score 0):

What is your other way of contacting Benjamin? I can not post on ThreeJS forum.

Comment: I DM-ed you via threejs discourse forum re IRFAN but it looks like you found someone or your project is not progressing.

Comment: Yeah! Sorry I'm lacking the time to answer on the recruitment for the project right now. I did not choose anybody yet. I did not have the time to look in details at all the profiles I received. What's your nickname on ThreeJS forum?
It does not mean I'm not interested anymore ;-)
Sorry for not replying yet...